# Put right permission - owner/group to public_html folder

Tags: permissions, centos, privileges, whm

I'm new to WHM, cPanel, and CentOS.

I install WHM then create an account for domain `app.example.com` and user `peter`
I point the domain name to right IP address but when I run my website app.example.com I got HTTP ERROR 500

Via SSH I log into the server and I find my previous uploaded code into

```
/home/peter/public_html
```

Then I run command `sudo chown -R peter:peter /home/peter/public_html`
and when I look at folders permission and owner they looks like:
[image]

I think my HTTP ERROR 500 is about user permission.

Can please help me to add right privileges to a user or what I need to do to my public_html folder be visible to the world (at browser).

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to know if it's a permissions problem, a bug in the programming of the web application or to see what really happens, is that you look at the log file of the web server (apache, nginx, the one you use). The log will give you more clues. Could you copy the log output when the error occurs?

Comment: @AleksPer depends on which web server you are running and where the installation was done. From what I understand, it is a shared hosting and, therefore, it was already "everything" installed? In that case, try searching in the cPanel, sometimes they place here the option to see the web server log in relation to your hosting.

Comment: You was right... I run composer update and I got this https://www.screencast.com/t/234E9BIkk1Pb What is this? How to solve thta issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems some required extensions were not activate or had been removed from your VPS. You should check and install/activate them. Then you can test your website again.
P.S: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: extension mbstring

Comment: You can use this command to try to install this extension: sudo yum install php-mbstring